# how to use google chart with angularjs for combo charts?

Tags: angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I have data like

```
  $scope.mychartobject.data =  [
    ['datetime','rx','tx','2.4',5'],
    [2014,6,7,2,3],
    [2015,8,9,1,2],
    [2016,2,4,6,1],
    [2017,5,6,8,4]
    ]
```

I need **rx** and **tx** in area chart and **'2.4'** and **'5'** in line chart.
I want both chart together in a single chart like this
[image]

I have created this chart in highcharts. I am migrating it from Highcharts to Google Charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.myChartObject = {
                'type': 'ComboChart',
                'data': {},
                'options': {
                    'title': 'Combo Chart',
                    'isStacked': true,
                    'series':{0:{'type':'line'},1:{'type':'line'},2{'type':'area'},3:{'type':'area'}}

                }
            };
```